# CFD inlet condition

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, software

I'm new to CFD and I developed compressible Euler equation CFD code.
But I couldn't calculate in the proper way. I got a bad result like the figure(gif).
[image]

So, I think my boundary conditions are wrong but I don't know what is wrong.

Please tell me what is wrong?
Here is my code at the inlet boundary.
I set inlet velocity, density, pressure, and energy term.

Thank you for reading.

```
! boundary condition at inlet
    do 200 i=0,N_Ghost-1
        do 201 j=0,j_max-1
            rho(i,j)=1.4
            u(i,j)=100.0 
            v(i,j)=0.0
            rhou(i,j)=rho(i,j)*u(i,j)
            rhov(i,j)=rho(i,j)*v(i,j)
            p(i,j)=rho(i,j)*Rgas*Temp ! Rgas=287, Temp = 15+273
            rhoE(i,j)=p(i,j)/(gamma-1.0)+rho(i,j)*(u(i,j)*u(i,j)+v(i,j)*v(i,j))/2.0
        201 continue
    200 continue
```

Comment: I am not sure my mistakes are at the inlet or other places. And I use FVM. So, Riemann solver or reconstructions are possibly wrong but I don't how to know that...

Comment: You might want to try this question on the Computational Science or [Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/#)

Comment: There is also a software tag on Materials Modeling Stack Exchange.